# i3status - Show either ethernet or wireless but not both

Tags: i3

I've been trying to configure my i3status bar to show wireless network when it's connected and ethernet when it's not.

As far as I can tell there is no option to display one status if the other isn't present.

Does anyone have any ideas.

I'm using i3status alongside i3wm.